# SAP HANA predictive analytics tool

Tags: prediction, hana

I have HANA installed in a server (RHEL 6.5) with HANA Studio. Now I want to do some predictive analysis in the data which is stored in the HANA database.

I know that there is a tool "HANA Predictive Analytics" for doing that.

But I do not know where to find if the tool is installed or we have to do it manually?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Lars Br. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

SAP HANA comes with an option to install the [Predictive Analysis Library](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_hanaplatform/helpdata/en/c9/eeed704f3f4ec39441434db8a874ad/content.htm?frameset=/en/71/a9ceee89734a79b18ae567e8f0fe70/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/32/731a7719f14e488b1f4ab0afae995b/plain.htm&node_id=3) which provides with the **backend** algorithms for many predictive use cases. These algorithms are available via functions and can be used directly in SQL, in SQLScript or in any other scenario.

Now, typically when people want to do something 'data sciency' they are looking for visualisations etc.
SAP has a solution for that - it's a separate program called "[SAP Predictive Analytics](http://go.sap.com/product/analytics/predictive-analytics.html)" which can leverage the PA Library in SAP HANA.

Sorry, if this reads like a marketing plug, but that's the SAP offering.

If you want to use the SAP HANA PAL w/o additional software, I highly recommend to check out the [YouTube videos of the SAP HANA Academy on that topic](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLkzo92owKnVw05sPUtcKJM66fYfk9sG-g).

Hope that helps with getting you started.

Answer (score 0):

The PAL documentation (available [here](http://help.sap.com/hana/sap_hana_predictive_analysis_library_pal_en.pdf)) has a section on how to find out whether the PAL is already installed and working, and how to install it if it's not. These topics are covered in chapter 2.

There is also a graphical workflow tool (the Application Function Modeler) that makes your life much easier when you're working with the PAL. It doesn't generate graphical output in the sense of ROC curves and the like, but it gives you a nice overview over your workflow, in much the same spirit as KNIME, SAS Enterprise Miner, SPSS Modeler, and similar tools. So you can avoid using the slightly inconvenient SQL-API of the PAL.